How do I change Visual studio's Output to powershell for a python script?
My school blocked cmd but not powershell so when I go to output my python code it can't because it tries to run it in cmd. How can I fix this? I think it is possible as I have seen something to do with changing your profile. I ONLY have access to powershell and even then still no admin so it might be hard. Image of my terminal

Please edit your question to clarify how you're running your Python script. The answer may depend on the specific method employed.

You can specify which terminal your program will run in by going into;
Settings > Terminal > External: Windows Exec
This option will allow you to specify the path of the executable of the terminal you wish to use. The default for me was;
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
change it to;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\powershell.exe
reference;
As you mentioned, you might run into some admin permission errors but it might be worth to give it a shot.

If you have PowerShell Core, the path might be something like C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe.
